# Django returns blank pages

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Suddenly I started getting **HTTP 200 with zero byte content** for every request handled by Django.

This problem has appeared in past, too, and seemed to randomly disappear.
I see a debug view when I make syntax errors, but if the code executes fine, I get a blank page.

I tried resetting Apache, moving project directory, removing `.pyc`'s—what next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mistake scores highest on **stupidness * impact** measure among all I've ever made.

I upload changes to our server via SFTP, and I got a short connection outage during last round of changes. Apparently, it happened exactly the moment I was uploading `base.html`, the base template for them all. The file was overwritten as zero byte empty file, and Django was correctly serving it.

Two things I've learned:

- to never trust SFTP clients;
- to inspect diff with `HEAD` when a problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me again. (I guess I'm lucky!)
I haven't found the cause but was able to recover by **stopping and then starting** Apache:

```
sudo apache2ctl stop
sudo apache2ctl start
```

Apparently, this isn't the same as restarting (`sudo apache2ctl start`) which didn't help at all.